# Mean.IO + Heroku Build Failing Error: ENOENT, no such file or directory '/app/bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.map'

Tags: node.js, heroku, gruntjs, mean.io

I have an app written using Mean.IO and deployed to Heroku (Buildpack https://github.com/mbuchetics/heroku-buildpack-nodejs-grunt).

It's been fine up until my latest deploy this morning and has broken for no apparent reason. Bower seems to be running fine

```
2015-01-06T00:09:50.851963+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: ENOENT, no such file or directory '/app/bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.map'
2015-01-06T00:09:50.851967+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Object.fs.openSync (fs.js:439:18)
2015-01-06T00:09:50.851969+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Object.fs.readFileSync (fs.js:290:15)
2015-01-06T00:09:50.851979+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Promise.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mpromise/lib/promise.js:177:8)
2015-01-06T00:09:50.851984+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Promise.fulfill (/app/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mpromise/lib/promise.js:97:20)
2015-01-06T00:09:50.851982+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Promise.emit (/app/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mpromise/lib/promise.js:84:38)
2015-01-06T00:09:50.851985+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Object.cb (/app/node_modules/mongoose/lib/query.js:1146:30)
2015-01-06T00:09:50.851981+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Promise.emit (events.js:95:17)
2015-01-06T00:09:50.851976+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Config.onPackageRead (/app/node_modules/meanio/lib/config.js:101:25)
2015-01-06T00:09:50.869507+00:00 app[web.1]: Worker 11 died :(
```

Relevant deploy code here

```
-----> Installing dependencies
       npm WARN package.json karma-chrome-launcher@0.1.7 No README data
       npm WARN package.json karma-coffee-preprocessor@0.2.1 No README data
       npm WARN package.json karma-coverage@0.2.7 No README data
       npm WARN package.json karma-phantomjs-launcher@0.1.4 No README data

       > mean@0.4.2 postinstall /tmp/build_f7b66ed6667be26db9cf377edd6379ea
       > node node_modules/meanio/node_modules/mean-cli/bin/mean-postinstall

       Installing Bower dependencies
       Auto installing package dependencies
       Auto installing package dependencies
       Installing module: mean-admin:
       git clone --branch master https://git.mean.io/linnovate/mean-admin.git packages/contrib/mean-admin
           Dependencies installed for package access
           Dependencies installed for package articles
           Dependencies installed for package system
           Dependencies installed for package theme
           Dependencies installed for package users
           Dependencies installed for package dashboard
           Dependencies installed for package linktexting


       > mean-health@0.1.7 postinstall /tmp/build_f7b66ed6667be26db9cf377edd6379ea/packages/contrib/mean-admin/node_modules/mean-health
       > node ./postinstall.js

       Error: ENOENT, open '.bower-cache/fe2fe255e91d251051d543998aa8327a-1.11.2.lock'
       gridfs-stream@0.5.3 node_modules/gridfs-stream

       mean-health@0.1.7 node_modules/mean-health

       request@2.51.0 node_modules/request
           Dependencies installed for package mean-admin
-----> Caching node_modules directory for future builds
-----> Cleaning up node-gyp and npm artifacts
-----> Building runtime environment
-----> Exporting config vars to environment
grunt-cli@0.1.13 node_modules/grunt-cli
├── resolve@0.3.1
├── nopt@1.0.10 (abbrev@1.0.5)
└── findup-sync@0.1.3 (glob@3.2.11)
grunt@0.4.5 node_modules/grunt
-----> Found Gruntfile, running grunt heroku:development task
Running "cssmin:core" (cssmin) task
>> Destination not written because minified CSS was empty.

Running "uglify:core" (uglify) task
>> Destination bower_components/build/js/dist.min.js not written because src files were empty.

Done, without errors.
```

I see the line

```
Error: ENOENT, open '.bower-cache/fe2fe255e91d251051d543998aa8327a-1.11.2.lock'
```

But I'm not sure what that means heroku wise. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Try running `bower update` it will install the missing jQuery dependencies

Answer (score -2):

From the documentation

http://learn.mean.io/#m-e-a-n-stack-more-information

```
**Update NPM, Bower or Grunt**

Sometimes you may find there is a weird error during install 
like npm’s Error: ENOENT. Usually updating those tools to 
the latest version solves the issue.

Updating NPM:
$ npm update -g npm

Updating Grunt:
$ npm update -g grunt-cli

Updating Bower:
$ npm update -g bower
```